# Django, nginx, gunicorn,supervisor: UnicodeEncodeError - when uploading non-latin named file

Tags: django, nginx, supervisord

When I upload some files with non-latin names I got error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /profiles/
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 39-41: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried change supervisor environment how it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715865/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character/10986010#10986010), but it didn't help. I've added this line in /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf:

```
[supervisord]
environment=LANG="ru_RU.utf8", LC_LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8", LC_ALL="ru_RU.UTF-8"
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)
```

When I put this line in program specific conf file it did not begin working too.

I've tried figure out my encoding, so I've add to template context this variable:

```
context['locale'] = sys.getfilesystemencoding()
```

and in template it shows "ANSI_X3.4-1968"

Could please someone explain why changing environment did not solve the problem?

Comment: Had you solved the issue? I have the same problem on Ubuntu.

Comment: Hello @RankoR, no we just moved to Python 3 %)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have completely restarted supervisord, as described [here](http://albertoconnor.ca/blog/2012/Jul/21/unicodeencodeerror-when-uploading-files-django-usi). Hope it helps!